Why does a segmentation fault occur in while?
I'm writing a program using shared memory segments. One process writes the string, the other reads it. If i is set to small values, then everything is fine. But why if you set 4, an segmentation error occurs. Please help
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 5, pid, status, shmid;
    key_t key, sem_key;
    
    int size = 8*pow(16, i);
    
    key = ftok(".", 'x');
    sem_key = ftok(".", 'y');
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, size + 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) exit(1);
    char *shmPtr = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    int sem = semget(sem_key, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    pid = fork();
    
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        int tmp_size = 0;
        while(semctl(sem, 0, GETVAL) != 1);
        char str[size];
        strcpy(str, shmPtr);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        char *s = shmPtr;
        char str[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            str[j] = '1';
            if (j == size - 1) str[++j] = '\0';
        }
        strcpy(shmPtr, str);
        semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);
    }
    wait(&status);
    shmdt(shmPtr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
    return 0;
}


Expect answer. Try understand by myself but didn't get it. Only undestand this happend in while.

"an error occurs" - details? "maybe because..." - you don't have to guess, add error handling to your code, check the error returned (shmget sets errno to indicate the reason for its failure).

str[++j] = '\0'; is out of bounds of the array str. I think you meant str[j] = '\0';. Or possibly char str[size + 1]; in both forks.

@IanAbbott Yes, I didn't notice. Fixed it, but the segmentation fault still appears

You wrote that the segfault occurs in the while loop which contains only a call to semctl, meaning the segfault occurs in semctl which is strange. Anyway add error checking to all of your sem* calls and see what happens. Also try to run your code with a debugger.

Stack frames have very limited size, you'll get a segmentation fault if you try to declare str[size] when size is too large. Use malloc() to allocate it in the heap.
